# How to get multi activerecord model with only 1 join query in Yii2?

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii, yii2

**For example:**

Query

```
 SELECT book.\*,author.* FROM book 
 INNER JOIN author ON author.id = book.author_id 
 WHERE book.id=1
```

Get model

```
$modelBook = Book::find()->innerJoin('author','author.id = book.author_id')->where(['book.id'=>1])->one();
$modelAuthor = Author::findOne(['id'=>$modelBook->author_id]);
```

**The problem:**

How can I get `2 activerecord model Book` and `Author` with just only one mysql execute?

I know that we can use `with()` function, but it spend another query `SELECT ...IN(...)` to get second model, although we have sufficient data from join query

Is there a more effective solution ?

Comment: ***qiangxue*** (if you know who is it) says `Performance wise, there is no proof that this approach is slower than the big join query. In some tests, it could be faster.` https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/2379#issuecomment-34573678

Comment: So you can simple use something like this `$modelBook->author` to get Author model.

Comment: @SiZE ofcouse we known him. And i known that Eager loading is better join about avoid bottlenecks. But maybe wasteful for some case

Answer (score 0):

ActiveRecord are  for model extendinng the ActiveRecord classe 
You seems are using a query and not a "model" so i suggest you of use activeDataProvider.

You can refer the models managed by dataProvider using getModels() function

```
       $provider = new SqlDataProvider([
         ......
    ]);



    // returns an array of data rows
    $models = $provider->getModels();
```

see this guide and reference for detail

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-providers.html
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-data-sqldataprovider.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

With approach is not slower in case of performance.

```
$modelBook = Book::find()->with('YOUR_RELATION_NAME_HERE')->findByPK(id);
```